# Como retornar um layout de cadastro baseado em uma opção selecionada do DropDownMenuItem Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Boa tarde pessoal!

Sou iniciante em desenvolvimento `flutter` e estou tendo dificuldades para conseguir retornar um layout de cadastro específico baseado na opção selecionada pelo usuário no DropDownMenuItem.

Basicamente, se o usuário selecionar **A** eu preciso que retorne apenas alguns TextFields para cadastro, enquanto se ele selecionar **B** retorne outros TextFiels.

Vou compartilhar o meu código com vocês...

Eu criei o MenuDropDown mas estou sentindo dificuldades para identificar onde colocaria as condições de analises. Busquei em alguns fóruns de perguntas mas não encontrei algo relacionado a minha dúvida.

Agradeço desde já pela ajuda!

```
      import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 class CadastroVacinas extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _CadastroVacinasState createState() => _CadastroVacinasState();
}

class _CadastroVacinasState extends State<CadastroVacinas> {



List _vacinas = ["A", "B"];

List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _dropDownMenuItens;

String _vacinaAtual;

@override
void initState() {
_dropDownMenuItens = getDropDownMenuItems();
_vacinaAtual = _dropDownMenuItens[0].value;
super.initState();
}

List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> getDropDownMenuItems(){
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> itens = new List();
for (String vacinas in _vacinas){
  itens.add(new DropdownMenuItem(
      value: vacinas,
      child: new Text(vacinas)
  ));
}
return itens;
}

void changedDropDownItem(String vacinaSelecionada){
print("Vacina selecionada $vacinaSelecionada");
setState(() {
  _vacinaAtual = vacinaSelecionada;
});

}

_deslogarUsuario() {
 FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
auth.signOut();

Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/login", (_) => false);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(
      color: Color(0xff4f4138),
    ),
    backgroundColor: Color(0xffffcc00),
    title: Image.asset(
      "imagens/logo_menu.png",
      width: 90,
      height: 80,
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
        onPressed: () {
          _deslogarUsuario();
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
  body: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Cadastrar",
            style: (TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff4f4138),
              fontSize: 30,
            )),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 10, top: 50),
            child: Text(
              "Selecione uma vacina:",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff4f4138),
                  fontSize: 16
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30),
            child: new DropdownButton(
                value: _vacinaAtual,
                items: _dropDownMenuItens,
                onChanged: changedDropDownItem
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
 );
 }
}
```

Comment: As condições podem ser feitas diretamente no teu método `changedDropDownItem` que será executado após selecionar algum item do teu DropDown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou lhe dar um exemplo de implementação e você tenta seguir o pensamento.

*Existem outras maneiras de se trocar um Widget, mas vou mostrar uma que acho legal.*

Crie uma variável na sua classe, chamada `PageController _controller = PageController();`

No teu método `changedDropDownItem`, faça a seguinte mudança:

```
void changedDropDownItem(String vacinaSelecionada){
  print("Vacina selecionada $vacinaSelecionada");
  setState(() {
    _vacinaAtual = vacinaSelecionada;
    _controller.jumpToPage(_vacinas.indexOf(vacinaSelecionada));
  });

}
```

E então implemente abaixo do seu `DropDownButton` um widget chamado `PageView`:

```
[...]
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30),
  child: new DropdownButton(
    value: _vacinaAtual,
    items: _dropDownMenuItens,
    onChanged: changedDropDownItem
  ),
Container(
  height: 500, // O tamanho que quizer
  widget: 500, // O tamanho que quiser
    child: PageView(
    controller: _controller,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children:[
      FieldsVacina1,
      FieldsVacina2
    ]   
  )
)
```

Exemplos de criação das classes com os campos

```
class FieldsVacina1 extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(),
        TextField(),
        TextField(),
        TextField(),
      ]
    )
  }
}

class FieldsVacina2 extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(),
        TextField(),
      ]
    )
  }
}
```

**Explicação**

Sempre que você selecionar uma opção do teu combo, será atualizado também a página atual da sua `pageView` mudando assim para os campos que deseja.
A classe `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` serve para que o usuário não consiga rolar entre as páginas.

Comment: Matheus Ribeiro, muito obrigada pela sua explicação. Ela foi sensacional!!!! Agora consegui fazer do jeito que eu queria :) Não querendo abusar, mais uma dúvida. Eu preciso informar o tamanho do Container? Porque eles são de tamanhos diferentes devido as informações. Tentei usar o SingleChildScrollView, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado! O `Container` ao qual dei de exemplo que possuí tamanho, pode ser removido e você seta o tamanho diretamente em cada Classe que for criar pros campos. Ai basta você ir ajustando pra ver como fica melhor pra ti

Comment: Matheus, você pode me ajudar novamente? Segui sua sugestão removi o Container da Classe inicial e adicionei na classe onde traria o layout específico de cada cadatro e configurei altura e largura para ele, mas na hora de executar o app ele apresenta o seguinte erro: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#b2322 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize' - fiz buscas em outros fóruns para erros como esse apliquei as sugestões, mas não funcionaram pra mim.